# Custom python package includes self as member

Tags: python, package

I have a simple python package that I am able to use and import, but that is behaving unexpectedly. The package structure is

> package_name
>
> > __init__.py
> >
> > modfile1.py
> >
> > modfile2.py

in __init__.py I have

```
import package_name.modfile1
import package_name.modfile2
```

If I open a python interpreter and

```
import package_name
```

I then see the following autocomplete choices (via jedi)

```
package_name.modfile1 package_name.modfile2 package_name.package_name
```

If I use package_name.package_name this can continue recursively. Why is the package listed as a member of itself?

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: Because it is imported that way with the full name. I don't know jedi but using a relative import "from . import modfile1" may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal.

`package_name.modfile1` would even exist if `__init__.py` were empty. It's just a module name, that you could import (with `import package_name.modfile1`)

same for `package_name.modfile2`

in `__init__.py` you import `package_name.modfile1`
So if you imported package_name, then the tab completion will offer you the symbols from  `__init__.py` within `package_name`

Thus you get `package_name.package_name.modfile1` and `package_name.package_name.modfile2`

Just comment the two imports from `__init__.py` and these symbols will disappear.

You could change the lines

```
import package_name.modfile1
import package_name.modfile2
```

to

```
import package_name.modfile1 as modfile1
import package_name.modfile2 as modfile2
```

To have a more consistent naming.

If you keep the `__init__.py` file empty

You have to use either

`import package_name.modfile1`
or
`from package_name import modfile1`

If  you have it populated with my last suggestion you can just use.
`import package_name`
and then directly access `package_name.modfile1`

Please note, that adding imports to the `__init__.py` file has one small side effect.

whenever you `package_name` `modified1` and `modified2` will **always** be imported into RAM. Even if you imported `package_name.modfile1` then `package_name.modfile2` would also be loaded into RAM.

Therefore I personally keep the init files almost always empty and import explicitly what I want.
exceptions being, where I know, that `modfile1` and `modfile2` will always be used together.

Just do whatever fits best your purpose.

Comment: If I remove the import statements in \__init\__.py and in the interpreter use import package_name, the modules are not available. If I instead use from package_name import modfile1 I get the expected results.

Comment: Exactly! This is how it works. Now just decide what behaviour you want and code accordingly. Please see my enhanced answer. Trying to elaborate a little more.

Comment: For a package like numpy, does this mean the entire package gets loaded into memory?  If a package that large loads into memory, the memory footprint of small packages must not be too great I would think.

Comment: if numpy has imports in its `__init__.py`, then yes.

Well I'm coding defensively out of habit, but you're right. this will probably not be a real issue for your package.